# Some apps doesn't run anymore in Linux Mint 18 (with Mate)

Tags: linux-mint, virtualbox, desktop-environment, mate-desktop

In Linux Mint 18 with Mate (running inside VirtualBox), some graphical apps don't run anymore. At least, no windows are showed and no processes keep running, after launching in the command line.

They finish immediately when launched (in the command line), some apps with this strange behavior: mintupdate, eclipse, xviewer, time-admin, nm-connection-editor, ...

Others that run: gimp, banshee, mate-terminal, LibreOffice, ...

What can be done to fix it ?

Comment: upgrade the apps?

Comment: Everything is up to date.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the 3D acceleration option in Display Settings of VirtualBox fixed the problem.

All graphical apps run again.